# electron 8.0.2 render process require is undefined and I have set nodeIntegration: true？？？

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, node-modules

[image]

[image]

```
new BrowserWindow({
    frame: true,
    height: 500,
    width: 800,
    WebPerferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true   
    },
    icon: './icon.ico'
  } 
 );
```

I can't use ipcRenderer in the rendering process now, is there any solution?

Comment: use `window.require('file'); instead of require()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mistake is quite obvious and fairly easy to spot: property names of an object literal are case sensitive and must be spelled correctly too. According to the [BrowserWindow](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window) documentation page, "**W**ebP**er**ferences" doesn't exist, but "**w**ebP**re**ferences" does...

The `webPreferences` option property not being found, its embedded `nodeIntegration` sub-option can't be found either.

This should be okay then:

```
new BrowserWindow({
    frame: true,
    height: 500,
    width: 800,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true   
    },
    icon: './icon.ico'
  } 
 );
```

Comment: It seems in the newest version `contextIsolation: false` is also required, i.e. `nodeIntegration: true` by itself is not sufficient to have access to `process` in the rendered process.